# JNI call equivalent to MultiByteToWideChar(...)?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface, jnienv

I was using WideCharToMultiByte, but I replaced it with env->GetStringUTFChars.

I now want to replace MultiBytetoWideChar with a JNI env equivalent call.

Does a call exist? Is it GetStringChars?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html

Comment: Thanks. Was looking for char* to jstring. And the documentation pointed me to NewStringUTF -- which suits my needs. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Java is very capable of converting between numerous character sets/encodings. JNI, itself, is not.

`NewStringUTF` takes a modified UTF-8 encoded Unicode string. `NewString` takes a UTF-16 encoded Unicode string but unless you are inter-operating with .NET, it's unlikely you'll have that.

Instead you should use create a Java `byte[]` array from your string, get a `String` constructor method and pass it the `byte[]` array and, optionally, the name of your character set/encoding. If you don't pass a character set/encoding, the JVM will use the current "native" one from your system (which could depend on thread settings, user settings, etc).